# When i share my python project that uses pip, how do i ensure that the user has the pip programs installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

I have a python project that uses tools/programs from the command line command called `pip`.
How do i ensure that the user has all the tools i'm using on their computer?

Do i have to include a readme that states you need the following tools in order to properly run the program, or is there some sort of function or module for me that can automatically install the missing features?

Oh, and i'm fairly new to Python, so maybe i just do not understand how pip works. Can i just use os.system("pip install something")? And what if i wanna be not platform specific?

Comment: Ideally you want to build your app (with `setuptools`) to be `pip install`-able. Then, whatever requirements you specify in your `requirements.txt`  will be automatically installed or updated as needed when the use does `pip install mypythonproject`.

Comment: jrd1's answer is good. About the portability of the way you described using `os.system`, one issue is you don't know whether `pip` refers to the Python 3 or 2 version, and there's no portable way to force either. It's annoying.

Comment: @sudo You can do `subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'something'])` and it will run the `pip` that comes with whichever Python the user is running to run your script. (Still not a great solution, but it solves the problem you're talking about.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is to include a `requirements.txt` which contains information on which packages need to be installed. You can read more [at the official documentation for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id1).

However, since generating that manually can be painful, there are tools like [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) which examines your project and generates a `requirements.txt` file for you by comparing your imports against those which are found through official pip repositories.

Once the `requirements.txt` file is generated, it can be installed this way: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll tick this in a few minutes as i cannot do that now, for some reason.

Comment: No prob, @RemigiuszSchoida - happy to be of service! I think that functionality is by design since SO wants you to have time to consider answers given. Thanks!